# If Stack Overflow doesn't have threads, what the heck should they be called?

Tags: support, terminology

Over the years, I've seen a lot of hullabaloo and holier-than-thou attitudes regarding the "we don't have threads here", oh not us, we're not like those uncivilized monstrosities called discussion boards. We don't have threads. We have *questions* and *answers*. *They* have threads, with their discussion and their banter and their threadiness of failure.

In other words, we have an initial post on a particular topic and the subsequent posts responding to that topic.

But how in the *kitten-petting* world is that different from a thread?

According to the Free Dictionary, [a thread may be defined as:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thread)

> A set of posts on a newsgroup, composed of an initial post about a topic and all responses to it.

The Jargon File has [this to say on the matter](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/T/thread.html):

> [Usenet, GEnie, CompuServe] Common abbreviation of topic thread, a more or less continuous chain of postings on a single topic. To follow a thread is to read a series of Usenet postings sharing a common subject or (more correctly) which are connected by Reference headers. The better newsreaders can present news in thread order automatically. Not to be confused with the techspeak sense of ‘thread’, e.g. a lightweight process.
>
> Interestingly, this is far from a neologism. The OED says: “**That which connects the successive points in anything, esp. a narrative, train of thought, or the like; the sequence of events or ideas continuing throughout the whole course of anything;**” Citations are given going back to 1642!

So even after 4 years and over 50,000 stackexchange rep, I'm struggling to figure out... how is (whatever the collection of posts that is a Question and its corresponding Answers is called) not a thread, and in the event there's a reasonable argument presented, what should an alternative single-word for such a collection be?

Comment: "Questions", or "posts".

Comment: A "Post" can be a "Question" or an "Answer". I'm looking for a single term that describes the collection of Posts that is one Question and its corresponding Answers.

Comment: Almost every time I've seen the term "thread" used on SO, it's in the context of answers like "I don't know how to start a new thread, so I'll ask my question here" or "I don't want to derail the thread, but I'm getting an error with your code..."

Comment: @cupcake also, simply giving the alternative doesn't address the issue of why thread is inappropriate in the first place.

Comment: Because a thread implies continuity from one message to the next, whereas all answers are a response to the question.

Comment: In the perfect SE world there shouldn't be threads only a Question and its definitive answer....

Comment: If "Post" doesn't work for you, how about "Q&A"? After all... That _is_ what it is.

Comment: A question and its associated answers (and comments) are arguable a thread, but the word carries a certain amount of baggage in the minds of some users who are new to Stack Exchange. Discouraging its use is an attempt to emphasize the extent to which these sites differ from other internet forums (another word we discourage not because it doesn't apply but because it carries a lot of baggage).

Comment: I have been using "Q&A" myself, as Kendra suggested. "Post" does not work because it means a single post; either a question or an answer. "Question" does not work because it means the question only. At any rate, I don't get why this *question* had to be downvoted.

Comment: @Kendra It's not that Post doesn't work for me - Post has a different definition in SE context. Every Answer is a Post, and every Question is a Post. As for "Q&A" I rather find it to be inelegant, mostly due to it not being a quantitative noun.

Comment: This could be an interesting question for one of the English language sites in the [se] network.

Comment: @DavidThomas I had considered it, but in this case the specific context of the community bears much more weight than the literal definition of the word itself.

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to find a more elegant way to put it. I find "Q&A" to be perfectly fine in the way of elegance myself. But I have always been a bit odd when it comes to terms- So take that as you will. Personally, I find "thread" inelegant- It makes me think of lose threads in clothing and such, and those bother me to know end.

Comment: Agreed, the question would have to include that as a requirement, I think; are the same concerns not evident, though, in those sites? It might not need to be articulated or explained quite so much (although, obviously, clarity would still be important).

Comment: If I need to refer to a question and its collection of answers, I always end up saying something along the lines of "This question and its answers" or "the answers to this question".

Comment: [I had the same doubt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161850/how-to-refer-to-a-stack-qa-item) on my early days of [se]. -1 for waiting 50k and being a mod to raise the non-issue...

Comment: @brasofilo While I did search heavily before posting this question, I didn't come across your question. Perhaps because it got migrated and I tend to forget to go to meta.se, old habits etc. However, the accepted answer there is exactly the kind of unrationalized response I encounter again and again - "we don't want it because we're not like those people" is not a rational thought process.

Comment: Listen, members of the secret club shall refer to the secret club using our agreed upon terms.  If an outsider comes in and calls us a club, we know he is alien and must be shunned.  That's how it works.  And it works great.  Whenever somebody wanders in and starts talking about threads we all know they are noobs and about to ask a book recommendation question.  Which is the origin of the rule, "If someone calls them Threads, we beat them to death."

Comment: @Will Yes but in 8 years no one ever came up with a reasonable replacement. "What are we gonna call threads over here?" "Well, we sure as hell ain't gonna call 'em threads, that's for sure..."

Comment: We call them Questions and Answers.  [OMG LOOK OVER HERE HE CALLED US A FORUM GET EM!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267828/is-it-ok-for-businesses-to-use-stack-overflow-as-their-official-support-forum)

Comment: Uh, *questions*..

Comment: Why not just call them Exchanges...?  Exchanging Q&A's.  A single exchange could be a question or answer....

Comment: Your OED definition of "thread" doesn't appear to fit the SE model. Answers don't have a defined order. You can sort by time, votes, or active. They are not supposed to be in response to previous answers. The only ordering is question -> (all answers).

Comment: Stack Overflow _does_ have threads. When I see "threads" I vote to close as opinion based (flag as too chatty if these are comments "threads")

Comment: @Will, OMFG, that's first class LOL, but you just broke *Fight Club's* 1st rule  =P

Answer (score 26):

The reason Stack Exchange doesn't have threads is that it's not a forum.

There's not meant to *ever* be a thread of discussion.

A Question is posted; it gets multiple answers. Every answer should be orthogonal to the others; and in the cases where an answer builds on all previous answers, you can still view that answer in isolation. Its existence is not dependent upon other answers.

You may argue that comments are 'threads' of discussion. They could be, except that they have none of the characteristics of a thread:  Any comment may be deleted at any time, for any reason. They're purposefully ephemeral.

If you need to refer to another Stack Overflow post, refer to it by its type (Question | Answer) or as a 'post'.  If you find yourself referencing something you think is a thread of discussion, that's a giant flag that something isn't going in a direction that's optimal for our format.

Comment: I completely agree that comments are completely out of scope for this discussion; they should merely be for clarification and should be considered expendable. I'm only considering the collection of posts that is a question and its corresponding answer. That aside, your logic doesn't make sense. Your first statement implies that threads are exclusive to forums, which isn't accurate, and your second statement implies that continued, unidirectional discourse is the only content of a thread, which also isn't accurate.

Comment: @corsiKa You could post a response explaining why my answer isn't accurate; but then that'd be building a discussion on my answer, turning this into a thread. Hrm. That doesn't seem like it'd be easy to follow. I'd better not invite you to respond, for fear that you'll prove my point you seem to imply isn't accurate.

Answer (score 12):

I think it's an issue of word association...

Here's what the typical SE user thinks of when they see word "thread":

[image]

And here's what they think of when they think of SE's Q&A:

[image]

The word thread has a lot of negative association, regardless of whether its usage would be semantically correct or not.

So, my suggestion is... <sub>drum roll please...</sub>

Go to [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and **try to get some sort of "Coin a new term for this *thing* we do..." competition going**, offer some sort of silly prize or a bounty and see if it gets any traction. Perhaps the community will come up with some new, less loaded, word.

Comment: Ah.. the glory of FHRC !!

Answer (score 3):

A question and its group of associated answers is often called a "Question".  Think of this as an OOP problem:

```
public Question {
  string QTitle
  string QText
  votes QVotes
  Answer A[]      
}
```

Questions have answers, which are associated specifically with that question: they don't exist outside of the question.  So, a question has a "Question Title", "Question Text", and "Answer[s]".  Thus, the entity is a Question.

On a forum:

```
public Thread {
  string TTitle
  post P[]
}
```

would be the generalized structure - a Thread has Posts.  Here, a Question has Answers.

(Yes, SO doesn't truly work this way in its physical structure, as pointed out; but that is related to how one implements a database efficiently.  Question-posts and Answer-posts are different in terms of how the site works; Questions have Answers, one to many relationship.)

As an example, this is how you would talk about the same thing on SO/SE and on a forum:

SO/SE:

> Did you see that question about snazzleboggles?  It got some interesting answers.

Forum:

> Did you see that thread about snazzleboggles?  It was an interesting discussion.

Hence, Question is the right word!

Comment: But that's not how SE is built. SE is built with a "Posts" object and a "PostTypeId" telling you if it's a question or an answer. See the schema on the side: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: That has everything to do with database simplicity and nothing to do with my thought experiment model.  SO/SE answers do not have a meaningful existence outside of the question they are tied to.

Comment: If Question can mean the question itself OR the collection of posts that is the question and its corresponding answers, then must have a collision somewhere. You can't call two things the same thing without something else to tell them apart.

Comment: One would expect contextual clues could typically differentiate, in cases where it actually matters (it usually doesn't).

Comment: Man, snazzleboggles are **so** 2013! No one uses *those* anymore!