# How was this comment edited ~5 years after it was posted?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-edits

I just came across a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428750/memory-leak-with-stdstring-when-using-stdliststdstring#comment3570156_3428750) that has been edited waayyyy after its grace period:

> Stop using `new` so much. I can't see any reason you used new anywhere you did. You can create objects by value in C++ and it's one of the huge advantages to using the language. You do not have to allocate everything on the **heap**. Stop thinking like a Java programmer.

The bold word changed from *stack* to *heap* sometime after November 2015.

Here is the latest snapshot of the page before the comment was edited: [Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20151128203926/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428750/memory-leak-with-stdstring-when-using-stdliststdstring).

Who did this? How is this even possible?

Comment: Moderators can edit comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well why though? Isn't that a bit problematic?

Comment: @Rakete1111: Why is it problematic?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, because there is no mention on who edited it. I know that it's probably not being abused, but it can.

Comment: @Rakete1111 There are all sorts of things that moderators can do that have a large potential for abuse.  That's why only trusted users are given moderation privileges.

Comment: @Servy I guess that makes sense. But isn't everything else documented?

Comment: @Rakete1111: this is why moderators are elected, sign a legal agreement and are monitored by the community moderator team (employees of Stack Overflow). What kind of abuse were you worried about?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not worrying :) Just a hypothetical question

Comment: @Rakete1111 To the public, no.  There are lots of actions a mod can take that a regular user doesn't have the capacity to audit.

Comment: Well then... I guess Mr. Skeet was active sometime after Nov 2015

Comment: @Rakete1111: as a moderator, I can see the revision history of comments. So if there is an actual *need* to track what happened with a comment, moderators (and CMs and other employees with a diamond next to their name) can still see what happened to such a comment. I don't think that ability needs to be extended to regular users at this point.

Comment: @Ihazkode What do you mean by that? Jon Skeet is not a diamond moderator and therefore cannot edit comments (beyond his own within the grace period).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisF I assume it was a comment [along these lines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Comment: It's interesting that it was a technical correction. It wasn't about removing rude/offensive material, or something like that. But, I guess it's possible the commenter asked a moderator to correct their comment.

Comment: @Servy never been a fan of that meme (no disrespect to Jon of course), but then I've never been a fan of the original "Chuck Norris" thing either ;)

Comment: This comment triggered more Q+A, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new/6501080).  Clearly it made sense to edit the comment.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that could very well explain the intervention.

Comment: The comment (and the ones following it) have been deleted/cleaned up now

Comment: It would be great if you could flag your own comment for edits...But the only option is to delete it

Comment: The answer to this QA is "Moderators can edit comments".  It's absolutely not my business, but as a passeryby, there does seem to be a **mindboggling** amount of discussion about such a trivial issue  :O

Comment: Note that with SO's whacky "you can't edit your own comments after five minutes!" rule ...  since every person alive now, well, every person under 89 years old, grew up with the "information! wants! to! be! free!" "open!! source!!" blah blah political stuff ..... what every user on SO does who wants to "edit" their own comments is simply delete and put in a new one.  In this case if it came from the original writer, that party should have just done that.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

That comment was flagged in August of 2016 by a community member with the following:

> Given how highly upvoted the comment is, and linked from another question with 500+ upvote, can the typo "stack" be fixed to what the rest of the comment clearly means - heap?

A moderator reviewed that and decided to edit the comment per the suggestion. We can edit any comment after the fact, but it does leave an indicator for moderators as to who edited it and when.

We tend not to edit comments, because they don't have the same kind of public edit history that other posts do. We usually decline flags telling us that comments are wrong or need to be corrected, but the moderator in this case had experience in the area. I generally only use comment edits to correct dead links or formatting errors, and even then only in rare cases when flagged by the community.

Comment: This is very sensible. My thanks to the moderator who saw it fit to make this edit.

Comment: @CodyGray of course is sensible: a piece of text that causes more work for everyone (the one that thinks that doesn't make sense, the one that takes it as true and it comes bitting them in the rear, the ones that has to explain that it's untrue, etc.) should move us to fix the root cause, be it, answer, comment, question, help page, wiki, ....

Comment: Wait… *deleting* all the comments, as has now been done, is *not* sensible! The comment in question was *clearly* useful, as testified by the vast number of users who had upvoted it. It did originally contain a typo, but that was fixed and order was restored. Why did they all need to be deleted? How is this making the Internet a better place?

Comment: @CodyGray - I disagree with the deletion of the original comment, so I've reinstated it and have been discussing this with the moderator who deleted these. The remaining comments largely addressed the old wording, so they were mostly obsolete.

Comment: I understand the arguments for comments being ephemeral, and I know people disagree on when comments should be removed, but the fact that this comment was interesting enough to become the subject of [its own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new) makes it seem worthy enough for it to stick around.

Comment: @BradLarson - given that [comments are ephemeral](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267824/541136), [comments aren't answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question) and thus answers go in the answers, if that information is so valuable, why don't you put it in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) where it can be properly voted on, cite the commenter, and flag it as obsolete?

Comment: @AaronHall: Because that requires a time machine, to have that other question link to the (now) answer instead of the comment. Including all other references. Do you have one and are you willing to share?

Comment: Like the wayback machine? https://web.archive.org/web/20151128203926/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428750/memory-leak-with-stdstring-when-using-stdliststdstring

Comment: @Aaron This is a case where leaving well enough alone is the best action. Having that comment there wasn't hurting anything. In fact, as I argued in my previous comment, it was making the Internet a better place by virtue of the information it imparted. I might find your argument a bit more persuasive if the mod who had deleted the comment had simultaneously put it into an answer and cited the original author. But that didn't happen; the useful information was just deleted. Comments being "ephemeral" is nonsense—they don't evaporate, they have to be *removed*, and there needs to be a reason.

Comment: I don't even agree that the comment should be made into an answer. The entire reason it was posted as a comment in the first place is because it's advisory information that doesn't attempt to answer the question (even if it does somewhat address it one way or another).

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here: https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q="comments+are+ephemeral"+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: [It's a meme alright.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT6ge.png)

Comment: @AaronHall: Are you seriously suggesting that it is better to put something, that *is* a comment (as well as valuable) into an answer, just so that it stops being *"ephemeral"*? Because, you know, that answer would then rightfully be flagged as *"Not an answer"*. Because it isn't. I don't understand the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @IInspectable I put a lot of connected information in my own answers, because I think it adds value. I have also created multiple answers to a question, in one, addressing the style of the code (like this comment does), and in another, actually solving the questioner's problem in an optimal way. The issue that this comment addresses can be easily put into an answer by a subject matter expert, where we can have version control, transparency of edits, and proper voting where it can "rise to the top" if it so deserves. This is a Q&A site, not a Q&A&Comment site.

Comment: @AaronHall: Again, you are hinting, that you do own a time machine. If indeed you do not, then you are arguing, how a perfectly disciplined Q&A site should run. But that completely misses the point: A comment was added (rightfully), voted on as valuable, linked to from multiple sources. You keep arguing, that in a perfect world, this shouldn't have happened. I'm sorry to break the news: You likely do not live in a perfect world, and have to deal with imperfections. You'll get used to it.

Comment: @AaronHall 'Comments are ephemeral' isn't a free pass to say all comments should be deleted without reason.

Comment: @AaronHall As a moderator, you have the ability to do great harm. To avoid doing so, I recommend you put being practical above being rigid. You should always be able to answer the question, "What is the substantive improvement caused by my actions?" I ask that question now: what substantive improvement is achieved by deleting this comment?

Comment: It would be great if you could flag your own comment for edits...But the only option is to delete it

Comment: @Honey You could raise a custom flag on the question requesting the edit. Alternatively, if the change makes a big difference, you could delete and repost the comment if it doesn't mess anything up (like responses). You could also leave a comment indicating the correction later.