# Should I flag a comment for editing if it is a mix of chattiness and helpfulness?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags

I didn't know comments could be edited until [I saw this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351003/3681880) today. What if a comment contains a mix of useful and useless content? Should I flag it to be edited?

Here is a contrived example (but not so very far from what I have often seen):

> Thank you so much for your answer! It was totally helpful! You saved me days of work! This should be the accepted answer! I think you have one small mistake in your code, though. It should be `xyz` instead of `abc`.

This comment would be better if the useless content was removed:

> I think you have one small mistake in your code. It should be `xyz` instead of `abc`.

I usually don't flag comments like this for deletion because they do contain some helpful information. I also don't usually edit the useful part into the answer and mark the comment as obsolete because it would be a code edit (or may even contradict the author's intention).

[Brad Larson ♦ indicated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351005/3681880) that editing comments is rare and usually requests are declined. Should I just leave these kind of comments alone?

Comment: For that kind of example, it's really a small typo, you could fix the typo, and if no-one objects to your edit (say a week later) flag the comment as obsolete. I've had people fix small typos in code on my answers, and I generally let those edits stand (or revert to those edits if community rolls it back).

Comment: Assume comments are frozen after the 5-minute grace period is up.  If it has no merit, flag it appropriately.  Otherwise, leave alone.  The circumstances where a comment should be edited occur something like one in a million questions — maybe less frequently than that — and you can safely assume that what you're looking at isn't one of those one-in-a-million occurrences.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

We try to avoid spending too much time moderating comments where possible. We only edit a comment if the comment is *extremely* valuable save for either a small but significant error that needs to be fixed for the comment to make sense, or save for a rude remark that needs to go away ASAP.

Chattiness isn't an example of something that absolutely needs to be edited out ASAP. Yes, it's annoying to read, especially when it makes up half of the comment text, but it's not nearly on the same level as, say, a comment with valid technical critique followed by "If you had half a brain you would have understood this."

If the comment as a whole is obsolete, for example because the mistake alluded to has since been corrected, I'd delete it entirely. Otherwise, I wouldn't waste my time on it.