# Was this comment deleted by a moderator or by mistake?

Tags: discussion, edits, comments, moderators, deleted-comments

There was a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256834/swift-guard-vs-if-let/32256911#32256911) by Rob himself. It had a small typo so I flagged it and asked a moderator to intervene and fix it and delete the following comments. But now the entire comment is deleted, and the rest of the discussion is still there :D

Was that a mistake? Or was it intended?

Comment: Flagging moderators to fix comment typos is a thing?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes!!! learned recently. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351003/how-was-this-comment-edited-5-years-after-it-was-posted). To be honest, if users have ability to edit answers, they sure can have maturity to edit comments, not sure why only mods have it. It's not really a needed thing. Perhaps a 5000 reps should have that privilege

Comment: @Honey that was a single comment with a score of more than 300, that was very much an exception to the rule. The ability to edit comments is almost never used by moderators, and in almost all cases the proper action is to either remove the comment entirely or to do nothing.

Comment: @MadScientist that only had a score of 300, because it's been there for almost 7 years. The other post is much more recent. Yet both were confusing. I just thought since moderators can...fix then also fix this. it's just cleaner to have them fixed. I don't know about that other question, but my hunch is that other folks also commented to point out its mistake and eventually it got fixed through moderator (whom also deleted the surrounding comments). I was hoping for the same. (1/2)

Comment: @MadScientist It wasn't just a typo like guard vs gurd. it was `guard if let` vs. `guard let` ie the extra `if` written by a top user who usually never makes mistakes made it more confusing. (2/2)

Comment: I'm not sure whether I got the downvotes for **asking the question** or for **flagging the comment**. As there is no similar question and this is a valid question. And its answer is: There is no criterion. That other edit got lucky...Additionally after asking this question, the deleted comment is placed back where it was. So I'm glad I asked

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Moderators *can* edit comments, but you shouldn't be bothering flagging moderators to come along and edit for minor things like this. Editing comments is meant to be used *incredibly rarely* for special circumstances.

It's *far more likely* that a moderator will interpret a "please edit this" flag as a "please delete this" flag. If something in it is wrong, it's easier to just delete it and move on. If there's some important information in there, it can be integrated into the post. Otherwise the user can re-post the comment in a corrected version if it's needed.

**TL;DR: Please avoid flagging comments for a moderator to edit them.** Your flag will either get declined or get the comment deleted 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Can you see my comment on the actual question.

Comment: Can you also diffrentiate the case between this comment edit and the this [accepted comment edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351003/how-was-this-comment-edited-5-years-after-it-was-posted). What differentiates these two?

Comment: The ease of the edit doesn't really change anything. Requesting an edit is just an inappropriate use of a comment flag, and just because one moderator decided to take action in one case does not mean you should continue casting flags in that manner.

Comment: Obviously. I just don't understand the criterion. Both comments were incorrect. Care to elaborate?

Comment: There **is no criteria**. A moderator randomly decided to step in for that particular instance. They could very well have just ignored it like any other situation. Other moderators probably would have,