# Can we work with Microsoft to improve the quality of questions they're referring to [botframework]?

Tags: support, outsourcing

In Microsoft's documentation for their Bot Framework, the very first link on their [support resource list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/resources-links-help) is as follows:

> **Community support**: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework)

Now, it's been established that using Stack Overflow for support like this isn't necessarily inappropriate given certain conditions are met, and to their credit, the Bot Framework team is doing a great job of monitoring the tag and helping to answer questions. However, it's been striking to me recently how large a percentage of questions in the [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) tag are lacking in elements essential for an on-topic Stack Overflow question (a clear and complete problem statement, code to reproduce the issue, an answerable, non-opinion based question, etc.). A few examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659821/whats-the-best-practice-for-building-precompiled-azure-function-based-bots), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664623/sorry-my-bot-code-is-having-an-issue-giving-error-in-all-the-channels), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650660/cortana-botframework-invocation). Likewise, I've seen questions where the template Microsoft provides for new issues on their BotBuilder GitHub issue tracker has been used as the template for a question here, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618516/how-to-start-new-proactive-conversation-dialog-without-ending-to-current-ongoing), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564927/why-botframework-bot-only-works-only-on-emulator-and-none-of-the-other-channels).

Is this a case where someone from Stack Overflow might be able to reach out and help the Bot Framework team better communicate to their users what kinds of questions are appropriate here versus what belongs on a GitHub issue tracker, and try to raise the question quality in this tag?

Comment: Can we at least get them to put the space in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Make a DB script that changes "Microsoft" to "Micro soft" every place it's used on SO untill they do.

Comment: Just a quick note that we've seen this, and that we're going to reach out to them. This can sometimes take a while depending on if / how quickly we get a response (especially from huge organizations); we'll start by reaching out to the folks most active in the tag that obviously work there.

Comment: Thanks @TimPost! Yeah, it definitely seems like there's a couple specific folks who're most active, so hopefully they'll be responsive.

Comment: It is never that obvious to me how a product owner can do what SO (the company) cannot do.  There is however another problem with owners helping out: they never moderate content.  Also a big problem with Microsoft's support group from Shanghai.  They post to *any* question and never close or vote on one.  They get paid to answer questions, not to get rid of them.  That wasn't so much of a problem in the olden days, community members usually got to them first.  But not anymore, and certainly not in niche tags.  A notable achievement of that Shanghai group was killing the MSDN forums btw.

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like the [references to "StackOverflow"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-framework-docs/search?utf8=✓&q=stackoverflow&type=) are part of a documentation project which is open-sourced on Github. Someone could hypothetically create a pull request with improved guidance around what should and shouldn't be sent here!

Comment: What a positively phrased, open minded, assuming-of-good-intent question.

Comment: @SamHanley Hypothetically, if someone did that, it would be nice if they posted the link back here. [*cough cough*](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-framework-docs/pull/62)

Comment: @svick sorry, got pulled away for an emergency work issue shortly after whipping up the changes/PR. Just came back here intending to post it and saw this!

Comment: And thanks for saying so, @FélixGagnon-Grenier -- I felt bad "complaining" because I genuinely really like/appreciate what Microsoft is doing in terms of community engagement. I just think we can make things better for everyone involved!

Comment: FYI @SamHanley While we're not a forum, SO does still refer to Q&A chains as "threads". "posts" isn't wrong (and it's probably better), but "threads" didn't *need* to be changed in your GitHub PR.

Comment: @TylerH, thanks for the info - is there a source for that usage of "threads"? I wasn't aware of that language being used officially, so I felt it should be avoided so as not to imply notions of being a forum, as you said. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267824/3486353) seems to indicate that, at least as far as one moderator is concerned, "threads" should not be used.

Comment: @SamHanley I don't have one off the top of my head; mostly questions, answers, and comments by devs/employees. Which leads me to believe it's probably just a momentary lapse on their part. Either way, "posts" is definitely better, because it helps separate us from the notion that Q&A chains as continuous/linear rather than a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I own the documentation for Bot Framework and I'm happy to effect the change that works out best for our customers and Stack Overflow. I'll approve and merge the PR when it's ready.

Comment: The Shanghai members now post comments to vague questions instead of answers.

Comment: @SamHanley This is first I've seen of this. Please reach out to me and let me know of any suggestions. I've been driving our support team for the past two years, and we're open to anything we can do better.

Comment: Hi @ChrisM. - this post was from a year ago, when the typical question quality was very low in the [tag:botframework] tags. The response we got from Robert was great, and (imo) things seem much improved since then. Thanks for checking in on it, though!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'm Robert. Long-time Stack Overflow user, first-time replier on this <s>thread</s> post. I'm the product manager for Bot Framework and I own the documentation.

I had a somewhat decent reason for linking to Stack Overflow directly – it's where we told customers to go when they had questions about how to build bots – but I think that's a brittle solution. If customers aren't getting answers in the docs *and* they aren't getting answers here because their questions are bad, then it's a lose-lose situation for them. The change you've proposed in your PR is a good one.

I will also talk with our support team to make sure they give customers the same information.

Comment: I think I stared at that coffee mug for too long.

Comment: For reference, [the mentioned pull request has since been merged](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-framework-docs/pull/62).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/resources-links-help

Answer (score 47):

As per my discovery that the documentation which links to Stack Overflow is part of an open-source project, I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-framework-docs/pull/62), contributing basic guidance based on the How To Ask guide in the help center. If merged, hopefully this will simply serve as a preliminary remedy, pending any larger future collaboration between the Stack Overflow & Microsoft folks.

If anyone has feedback on the content, wording, etc. - please feel free to weigh in.

Comment: You could add space in "StackOverflow -> Stack Overflow", as mentioned above.

Comment: @VadimKotov, do you see an instance where I didn't correct that? I glanced over it again and don't see that.

Comment: Take a look at " contributor-guide/tools-and-setup.md", line 5

Comment: Ah, good catch! I'll follow up on that.

Comment: Pull request merged!