# Modify [botframework] tag to [botframework-v3] or merge all [botframework] as v4 is now the stable release?

Tags: discussion, tags

### Context

There are currently 2 main tags about Microsoft Bot Framework:

- [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) which was the main tag for all question for more than a year, as the v3 of the framework was stable
- [botframework-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework-v4) which has been created to post questions specific to this v4 version, where the architecture has been really changed (so questions were often not linked to v3 anymore)

Microsoft Bot Framework in version 4 is officially stable for a few days (see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/microsoft-bot-framework-v4-sdk-is-now-generally-available/)).

### Evolution?

I'm wondering if we should:

- edit [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) to something more "specific" like [botframework-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework-v3)
- or merge [botframework-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework-v4) tag to [botframework].

### Why?

I'm one of the top repliers of [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) and I see many people using this "now old" tag for v4 related questions, so there are many question wrongly tagged. I would like to discuss about which scenario would be the best one, between putting everything in the same place (I'm sure there will be questions related to v3 for a few months) or splitting with the tags.

---

#### Edit 23/10 - Details about what has been done

On the 22nd of October, no replies have been provided to this question, only a few comments from @Braiam. So I made the changes to modify questions with [botframework-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework-v4) to [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework).

Following this, a discussion has started on this topic, including people from Microsoft who work on Bot Framework. This ended by keeping the modifications of the tag to get only one [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework), and @Braiam made a PR on Microsoft Github's repo to avoid pointing to [botframework-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework-v4).

Finally, for future questions like that, it may be important to suggest people to duplicate (or link) their question to what is now the "parent" Github repository, https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder ?

Comment: There are only 37 questions and you have 2k. You can simply retag all the -v4 question to the non-suffixed tag.

Comment: That's the 2nd proposition yes. But merging everything inside 1 tag can be subject to discussion, hence this topic

Comment: I'm suggesting that as the easier solution that can be done right now without intervention of a moderator. Merging and retagging are the same thing for all purposes, so you are discussing whenever or not should you make a moderator do it for you.

Comment: @NicolasR Thank you for raising this.  We are having some internal discussion on the Bot Framework Support team about this. Historically, how are tag versions handled in other cases on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My preference is the "one tag" model. When we introduced the "-v4" tag, I don't think anyone really thought about the friction this could cause, or how the support matrix would continue to become increasingly complex over time. For example:

- As we approach "4.1" later this month, should we consider a "-4.1" tag?
- Should there be a "-v4-java" tag?
- Should we introduce a "-tools" tag?
- [...]

The answer is clearly no as it would quickly become unsupportable.

The Link in our [C# Readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/README.md), was added simply as I have an addiction to GitHub Badges.

Braiam has graciously already [submitted a PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/1051) to remove this tag from the branch and that PR has been merged.

Comment: Note - I should add, I mange the BotBuilder repos, as well as our team of support engineers. Sometimes I'm even able to find the time to write code. :)

Comment: Chris, ★Nicolas R ★, the one who opened this, is the one Jason and I were telling you about a few months back.  He contributes to our GitHub repos as well.  SUPER helpful!  Should be MVP!!!  :)

Comment: Thanks ChrisM. for this clear reply, I'm in line with your opinion. The v4 was here to avoid mixing questions during the beta period, now it's over. Thanks @Braiam for the PR

Answer (score 3):

If action is being taken to straighten out the usage of these tags, it needs to involve coordination with Microsoft. Microsoft is notable in terms of third-party players in terms of how many places they link to specific Stack Overflow tags. In this case, they link to the (now soon-to-be-deleted) [botframework-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework-v4) tag in the `readme.md` of [the Bot Builder SDK v4 Github repo](http://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet).

At the very least, we should make sure that MS is aware of any changes being made to these tags, and arguably, they should be able to weigh in on what lines to draw between the different tag versions. Arbitrary changes to which tag is being used for which version are likely to cause deprecation of a *lot* of other links, especially if you propose moving v3 questions off of the [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) tag (which seems like a required next step if you're attempting to repurpose that tag to refer to v4).

There's precedent for collaborating on this, as we have engaged them in the past regarding [efforts to clean up the question quality in the Bot Framework tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357645/can-we-work-with-microsoft-to-improve-the-quality-of-questions-theyre-referring), to good results.

Comment: I understand your points, that's also why I posted this question initially but my main problem was: how should we ask them? I also think that these tags must be managed by the community (By the way it's not Microsoft people who created this v4).

Comment: You could ask them by contacting the Stack Overflow user who answered the prior post I linked, who identified himself as being the the product manager for Bot Framework and owner of the documentation. Or you could open an issue on the Github repos for any of their documentation which you've broken by unilaterally deleting this tag - I linked you to at least one such instance. But deciding to "manage" these tags without care for breaking existing links is harmful.

Comment: This man never contributed so either [tag:botframework] or [tag:botframework-v4]. This tag management "without care" has been made to help people asking question to get proper replies, because it was just a mess as people did not follow the documentation you mention and are posting in either one tag or the other. By the way I also have made an edit to the tag description to ensure that the information are correct (fixed linked that Microsoft also broke on their side...) so my contribution was not made to break everything as you mentioned, sorry

Comment: I didn't intend to start a dramatic confrontation - I certainly don't think it was your *intention* to "break everything". I'm only trying to draw attention to information that I felt needed to be taken into consideration. I really didn't expect such a defensive reaction given that the point of this question was to solicit community input on a potential change, and I'm sorry if any of my response pushed this to be unnecessarily contentious. As someone who has both asked and answered questions in the [tag:botframework] tag, I assure you I share your goal of improving these tags.